# How to set AlarmManager set method twice

Tags: java, android

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

int minute = 2;
time.add(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);


AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(TimeSequenceActivity.this, TimeSequenceReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TimeSequenceActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int another_minute = 1;
time.add(Calendar.MINUTE,another_minute);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

---

I wan to set AlaramManager twice. 
for example) want to set alarm in 2 minutes, and also set alam 1 minute after 1st alarm. so type above code and excute application, it is now working that the alarm is fired in 3 minutes just one time.

Thankg you in advance..

Comment: You need 2 alarms with 2 distinct pending intents. one set to shoot after 2 minutes and the other one set after 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem from other person's question.
solutions is as below.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TimeSequenceActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TimeSequenceActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

If I want to set different alarams then should be another `requestCode` in `PendingIntent`.